# About selenium frameworks

Tags: selenium

I am a beginner in software testing. I am doing selenium automation. 
I want to know the selenium frameworks. 
What is the importance? I found the frameworks like data driven, keyword driven and hybrid. I want to know which framework is most people using and why?

I am following page object design pattern later I understand that my code doesn't follow any frameworks so I need to to know the importance of frameworks. I am keeping my test data in properties file. so which is the most suitable framework for properties file

Comment: I think you have to keep your test data in XML file or Excel file. That will easier for you..

Answer (score 2):

You will get a very comprehensive reading here:
[Selenium Wikilink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software))

About which framework is the most used ones, I do not think there is a statistic about it. It is contextual, will vary case by case.

For your last question, I do not understand what you meant by properties file, can you please elaborate?

-------------------Update--------------------

OK, you are talking about data-driven testing. E.g. you separate test data from scripts that are using them.

From my personal experience, all of testing framework can be customized / extended to accommodate data-driven methodology. E.g. all testing framework can accept external data as parameters / resources. Of course, it may take you some time and effort on reading test framework documentation to make it work.

Have a read there, [TestNG and data driven testing](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/testng/testng-dataprovider-example/)

Comment: To keep the the test data separately like properties file  key =value.

Answer (score 2):

**Purpose of keyword driven frameworks compared to data driven frameworks.**

Keyword-driven testing is a technique that separates much of the programming work from the actual test steps so that the test steps can be developed earlier and can often be maintained with only minor updates, even when the application or testing needs change significantly. The keyword-driven testing methodology divides test creation into two stages:    Planning Stage, Implementation Stage

Data- Driven testing is a framework where test input and output values are read from data files (datapools, ODBC sources, csv files, Excel files, DAO objects, ADO objects, and such) and are loaded into variables in captured or manually coded scripts. In this framework, variables are used for both input values and output verification values. Navigation through the program, reading of the data files, and logging of test status and information are all coded in the test script.

**What circumstances would make a keyword-driven framework more appropriate for an automated test suite than a data-driven framework?**

The keyword driven automation framework is initially the hardest and most time-consuming data driven approach to implement. After all, we are trying to fully insulate our tests from both the many failings of the automation tools, as well as changes to the application itself.

To accomplish this, we are essentially writing enhancements to many of the component functions already provided by the automation tool: such as error correction, prevention, and enhanced synchronization.

Fortunately, this heavy, initial investment is mostly a one-shot deal. Once in place, keyword driven automation is arguably the easiest of the data driven frameworks to maintain and perpetuate providing the greatest potential for long-term success.

For More Understanding [read this](http://safsdev.sourceforge.net/FRAMESDataDrivenTestAutomationFrameworks.htm)